# Structure constant of the commutators of generators in broken symmetry

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra, symmetry-breaking, commutator

When I read a paper related to spontaneously global symmetry breaking, I cannot understand a statement:
If we use the notation $T^i$ for the unbroken group generators in $H$ and $X^a$ the broken generators in $G/H$. In general they have the following commutation relations

$ [T^i, T^j]=if^{ijk} T^k,\quad [T^i,X^a]=if^{iab} X^b,\quad [X^a,X^b]=if^{abi} T^i+if^{abc} X^c$.

Why for symmetric coset, $f^{abc}=0$ in the last commutation relation? I don't understand this point.

Can someone help to explain this detail?

Comment: What is a "symmetric coset"?

Comment: I am sorry, I also have no idea about this concept. I saw the statement in the paper arXiv/hep-th: 1412.2145.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is only the definition: the Cartan expansion, which is given by set of operators $T_{i}, X_{a}$ with corresponding commutation relations, where $T$ represent the set of generators of $H \in G$ subgroup, while the $X$ denotes the set of other operators of group $G$ in basis with fully antisummetric structure constants (such basis always exists for compact groups).

Then, by the definition, the coset $G/H$ space is called symmetrical space when the set of structure contants $C_{abc}$, which are defined through
$$
[X_{a},X_{b}] = iC_{abc}X_{c} + iC_{abi}t_{i},
$$
is equal to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I understand it now. I made the definition and its consequence reversed before.